# asp.net url rewrite with dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I use asp.net C# and need a to make an URL rewrite rule that maps a long URL to a short url, and keep the dynamic URL parameter (guid):

**Example:**

The first URL (short) should be mapped / redirected to the long url below:

Short URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/campaign.aspx?guid=db7b1e74-f45a-4756-945f-33e812534c09
```

Long URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/templates/sections/user/misc/campaign/freemember.aspx?guid=db7b1e74-f45a-4756-945f-33e812534c09
```

The GUID parameter is dynamic created, so I cannot hard code that in the rewrite rule. Hope someone can help me creating this rewrite rule :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteUrl">
      <match url="^campaign/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/templates/sections/user/misc/campaign/freemember?id={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not had to do this before, but maybe this will be of use to you.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/shorturl-dotnet/

Comment: I need to make a web.config rule that dynamically converts / maps the short url to the long url and keep the GUID parameter.